# Creating battery pack with biased thermistor resistor network. How to ground if sensing externally

Tags: grounding, temperature, circuit-protection, batteries, sensing

I designed a battery pack board for a customer that uses a multi-cell low-side (NMOS) protection IC. The protection includes OV, UV, OC, and OT/UT protection for the pack. The Overtemp and Undertemp protection is based on a bias network from the protection IC, with a thermistor tied to this network. The temperature is determined from a % of the bias voltage to this network, so it is independent of that bias voltage. This pack connects to another board via a 4-pin connector, one pin which outputs a 3-level voltage (HIGH, MID, LOW) such that the other board can detect OT, NORMAL and UT states.

However, because the protection IC disables the N-FETs when there is an OT/UT fault, I will lose the GND connection to the other board, making this tri-level digital signal useless, I think. **So should I ground this differently and tie the digital signal output to the pack-side of the board, or keep it on the cell side?**

[image: Snippet of schematic]

To better understand what I'm doing in the schematic here:

U2:VTB and U2:TS form the thermistor bias network. Originally, I was going to buffer out the U2:TS voltage directly to monitor the temperature, but the U2:VTB bias voltage has a wide range (2.1-3.25V), so it's difficult to make a judgement about the temperature without having access to the VTB pin on the other board (the 4 output pins of the pack are BATT+, BATT-, TEMP_SNS, and BATT_SNS). So instead I opted to provide fixed voltage levels when the OT and UT thresholds trip.

U5 is a comparator which closely matches internal U2 OT/UT thresholds. U3 is a 4:1 mux that takes the output of the comparator and sets 50%VTB when all normal, VTB when cold, and GND when hot. Then this signal is driven through the buffer, U4 out of the pack.

Again, my question is more about the ground reference for this circuit which sits before Q1 and Q2 (cell side). However, the other board is ground referenced to the BATT- side (after Q1 and Q2). And I don't know if it will be able to sense the voltage output of that aforementioned circuit if the protection trips. When the protection circuit trips, the only connection to cell GND (not shown) is through the U2:LD pin, which is meant to detect when the load is removed in order to re-enable the pack protection FETs.

Comment: have you considered isolating?

Comment: What do you mean by isolating Scott? Isolating what part of the circuit?

Comment: I didn't analyze your circuit in any detail at all, but if you're having trouble connecting the grounds of two systems, one approach that can always be considered is making it so the grounds don't need to be connected.  You can use isolated DC/DC converters or batteries, or separate power supplies to provide power, to each side, and an isolator (usually magnetic or isolated) for any signals.  Digital isolation is likely easiest, but it can be done for analog signals also.  In some ways, this can be a more expensive  approach over doing it right, but if time is important....

Comment: Oh no, I can't do that on this. This is a non-isolated design. The battery connects directly to another board and serves as the ground for that board. This circuit is just meant to protect the battery pack by opening the ground connection in one direction.